# Why am I getting different hashcode values using hashcode builder for 2 equal objects?

Tags: java, groovy

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            HashCodeBuilder hashCodeBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder();
            hashCodeBuilder.append(this.getId()).append(this.getDocFamilyUuid())
                           .append(this.getCorrelationId());

            return hashCodeBuilder.hashCode();
        }
```

This is how I'm creating the object in groovy. The fields are being set to static constants

```
DocInfo docInfo =  new DocInfo(id:DOC_ID, correlationId: CORRELATION_ID, docFamilyUuid: DOC_FAMILY_UUID)
```

And I'm trying to assert

```
assert docInfo.hashCode() ==
           new DocInfo([id:DOC_ID,
                   correlationId: CORRELATION_ID,
                   docFamilyUuid:DOC_FAMILY_UUID]).hashCode()
```

Comment: Please give more information about which HashCodeBuilder you're using - which library, and which version. This is absolutely *crucial* information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're calling `hashCode()` instead of `toHashCode()`, assuming you're using the [commons-lang HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html). In other words, you're getting the hash code of the builder itself, rather than the hash code it's building :)

Now the odd thing is that they're documented to return the same thing in the version of the JavaDoc that I've linked to. So I wonder whether you've got an old version - or possibly you're using an entirely different `HashCodeBuilder` entirely...

EDIT: Yup, `HashCodeBuilder.hashCode()` is overridden in version 2.5+ to return `toHashCode()`, but the OP is using version 2.3, which doesn't work that way.

Comment: Suttle, but important difference... :)

Comment: @ErikA.Brandstadmoen: Perhaps. It depends on whether I'm right or not, which depends on knowing what *exact* HashCodeBuilder the OP is using.

Comment: I'm using the org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

Comment: @JonSkeet: But you made a pretty good guess, didn't you? And, turns out you were right.

Comment: @Phoenix: Okay - it looks like `hashCode` was overridden in version 2.5 to return the same as `toHashCode`. Have you thought of upgrading to a version which is less than 5 years old? :)

Comment: I could but I need to basically modify some old code. So, I don't want to break anything.